# How to call a function in JavaScript by typing out the function name in a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

how to call a javascript function typing it in a HTML textbox. For example I want to call myFunction() and it returns "Hello". How do I make it so that when I type myFunction() in a HTML textbox it will return "Hello" which I can use to add into a div.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `eval` Javascript Method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Depending on the code you are using you could do something like:

```js
const textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
const value = textBox.value;

eval(value);
```

Be warned that eval is a dangerous method and allows the user to run any Javascript they want. T(h)read carefully.

Comment: `Thread carefully.`  that is certainly good advice, threads are a pain.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This method implies all functions you are going to call are stored in one object, lets call it `myObject`.

First, you should get a value from a textbox HTMLElement. For example:

```
const val = document.getElementById('textbox-id')?.value;
```

Then make sure your object with functions has property with given name and it's actually callable:

```
const hasProperty = myObject.hasOwnProperty(val);
const isCallable = myObject[val] inctanceof Function;
```

And just call it using property accessor:

```
if (hasProperty  && isCallable) {
    myObject[val]();
}
```

**EDIT:** in this case value in textbox should be without brackets. If this is the point, just use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method